# How to change cell background color on click cell in table?

Tags: asp.net

I need to change the color of the cells on сlick (only 2 colors: black and white), and then analyze the colors of cells to form an array with values​​: 1 - black, 0 - white?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code to toggle the color

```
onClick="this.style.backgroundColor=='black' ? this.style.backgroundColor='white' : this.style.backgroundColor='black';"
```

And you get the Colors using this function

```
var tds = document.getElementsByTagName("td");
for(var i=0; i<tds.length; i++)
{
alert(tds[i].style.backgroundColor);
}
}
```