# Color updated Grid View cells in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, gridview

I am creating one web application in ASP.NET. What I want is when the invoice is created and when the quantity or amount is changed in the `GridView` then the rows effecting that `GridView` cell should get a highlighted color for some seconds and then get back to normal as they were.

I just want to catch the eye of the user that the values changed.

Comment: You can assign a css class and toggle it by using say [setTimeout](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want a variation of the answer to this question:
[How to change the gridview row colors in onclick event in javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819638/how-to-change-the-gridview-row-colors-in-onclick-event-in-javascript)

Rather than binding to the entire row, you would want to add the javascript function to an event associated with the quantity and amount field:

```
e.Row.Cells(x).attributes.add("onblur", "ChangeRowColor(this)");
```

Note: be careful here as `onblur` wont handle all changes.  You might want to review [Detect all changes to a <input type="text"> (immediately) using JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1948332/detect-all-changes-to-a-input-type-text-immediately-using-jquery) to detect all changes to your field.

Then in order to make your row "highlighted" you would find it easiest to use [jQuery's Highlight](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Effects/Highlight) effect.