# change color of a cell using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I coded one java script for changing color of a cell of a gridview in asp.net.The function is given below.

```
        function hello() {
            var gvDrv = document.getElementById("<%= gridviewSearchResult.ClientID %>");
            for (i = 1; i < gvDrv.rows.length; i++) {

                var cell = gvDrv.rows[i].cells;
                var HTML = cell[0].innerHTML;

                if (cell[1].innerHTML == "Combivent") {
                    gvDrv.rows[i].cells[2].className = " PendingRowStyle";
                }
                else {

                }
            }
         }
```

If the cell content is "Combivent" , I am applying CSS class `PendingRowStyle`  for a column.

I'm calling this function on a button's `onclientclick` event.

Now the issue is , its changing the color of the cell as per the condtion. But as soon as changed its retaining to old stage. Its just like blinking that color to the cell.Why that color is not persisting to that cell.What is the logic in that? How i have to handle this?

Note: I loaded the gridview in the pageload event , inside if(!ispostback).

Can any one give me a solution?

Comment: Careful with `i` => `var i=1`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819638/how-to-change-the-gridview-row-colors-in-onclick-event-in-javascript?rq=1

Comment: What you mean?can you explain a bit?

Comment: If you can, use a server side approach replacing the boundfield column with a template column + binding properties to change the style.

Answer (score 0):

In page load

```
if(!isPostback)
{
 FillGridview()
}
```

and in the server side button click

```
protected void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onclick", "<script anguage=javascript>hello();</script>");   

}
```